# Flashing/Flickering in Mega Menu on Link Hovers

Tags: javascript, css, megamenu

Please look at http://my-webpresence.com/work/yasir/dinecart/menu.html#.

When you hover over the restaurants in the top menu and then hover over 'Browse' and then on any of the links in the menu, the entire menu 'flashes/flickers' as you move over ANY of the links.

What is the problem and how can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a complete solution, but it might help you locate the primary issue. Each time you hover over one of the top links "Featured" "New Restaurant" "By Category" "By Location" "See All", the li under #flyout-menu goes from "active selected" to "browse" to "active selected". That's when the flickering is occurring.

It may have something to do with this function here:

```
        $("#flyout-menu li").hover (function () {
            $("#flyout-menu li > div").hide();
            $("#flyout-menu li").removeClass('selected');

            $(this).addClass('selected')
            $(this).children('.nav-sub-1-right').show();

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Flyout menu javascript hides the `<div>` for a moment while you remove and re-add the selected class on your `<li>` nodes. then the `<div>` is redisplayed.  This causes the flickering.  Don't hide the `<div>`.